# remove multiple and double brackets with dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I need to remove the individual brackets, until I was able to remove the individual brackets. However, the location column has two square brackets and I cannot remove it.

```
  value           car             location
[R$ 40.590]   [FIAT ARGO]   [[São, Paulo, (SP)]]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwFRt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df.location = df.location.str[0]
```